# $X$ is a compact metric space, then is $f(X)$ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $(X,d_X)$ is a compact metric space and $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I am trying to show that $f(X)$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$ but I am not sure how to go about doing so.

Any hints?

Comment: You probably also have an assumption that $f$ be continuous.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** I assume you intend for $f$ to be continuous. Do you know that the continuous image of a compact space is compact? And do you know that compact subsets of $\mathbb R$ are bounded?

Note that if $f$ needn't be continuous, and if $X$ is not finite, then you can construct an $f$ which is unbounded on $X$: just pick an infinite sequence of distinct points $x_n\in X$ and define $f(x_n)=n$, choosing $f$ arbitrarily on other points (say, $f(x)=0$ if $x\notin \{x_n:n\in \mathbb N\}$).